# TabLayout disappearing behind ViewPager in CollapsingToolBar

Tags: android

Im trying to create an AppBarLayout using the CollapsingToolBar which contains a Toolbar and a TabLayout and im also using the app:behavior_overlapTop attribute on my RelativeLayout which includes a ViewPager. The problem is that when the CollapsingToolBar is expanded my TabLayout disappears behind the ViewPager as the TabLayout is given a layout_gravity = bottom and due to the fact that i have used app:behavior_overlapTop on my RelativeLayout which includes the ViewPager. How can i fix this ? Thanx in advance.

( This is my first question here, sorry if have missed anything, i would have included images for better understanding of the problem but i dont have enough repo )

Here is my XML file
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/beats"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:titleMarginBottom="60dp"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp"
        >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`

Comment: tabs layout should be outside collpasingtoolbarlayout.

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar - when i put tablayout outside collapsingtoolbar it then disappears behind the RelativeLayout which include the ViewPager, previosly it was disappearing behind the ViewPager when it was inside the collapsingtoolbar.